# RedHat - How to stack folders?

Tags: rhel-5

Every time I open a folder and double-click on another folder inside, another folder opens up.  If I am finding a file burried in a folder, many folders will open before I can reach the file and then I will have to close them all. Can I somehow configure my machine so that it uses the same folder like in Windows?

Comment: What does: "same folder like in Windows" mean?

Comment: Well, like in Windows XP, if you open a folder, only one folder opens. Then when you keep opening the folders in that folder, you are using the same folder. You don't open even more folders like how RedHat 5 behaves.

Comment: O_O means "in the same window".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In GNOME 2.6, the Nautilus file manager uses "Spatial" file management mode by default. What you are looking for is the "Browser" mode.

Go to *Edit → Preferences*, click the *Behaviour* tab, and enable the *Always open in browser windows* option.

(As for "like in Windows" – Windows 95 used spatial mode by default too.)